# Instead alpha mathematical symbol i get ff

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I was writting this line:

```
$d: a\ped{x}.b\ped{\alpha} \implies(\lor\ped{i=1}\ap{m}(\land\ped{j=1}\ap{k\ped{i}} L\ped{i\ped{j}}))$
```

Instead get the alpha I get a strange "ff". Someone can explain what's wrong in the code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you make a complete example? For example, the definition of `\ped` is missing.

Comment: You should type `a_{x}`, not `a\ped{x}`; with `babel-italian`, `\ped` is defined for *textual* subscripts. Similarly, `\ap` should not be used in math mode: type `\bigvee_{i=1}^m` (and `\bigwedge` instead of `\land`) when it takes limits.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the definition of \ped. 

Thanks for your answer egreg. Problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me you have

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
```

so the commands `\ped` and `\ap` can be used in text mode for *textual* subscripts and superscripts respectively.

For subscripts and superscripts in math mode you should use `_` and `^`:

```
$d: a_{x}.b_{\alpha} \implies(\bigvee_{i=1}^{m}(\bigwedge_{j=1}^{k_{i}} L_{i_{j}}))$
```

Note that `\lor` and `\land` should be `\bigvee` and `\bigwedge` when their use is similar to that of summations.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

In text abc\ped{x} or abc\ap{y}, but in math
$d: a_{x}.b_{\alpha} \implies(\bigvee_{i=1}^{m}(\bigwedge_{j=1}^{k_{i}} L_{i_{j}}))$

\end{document}
```

[image]